# codeigniter calling empty_table before insert_batch

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table(myTable) with 3 fields:

```
ID (int), posistion(int), products_id(int)
```

I have an form where we can change the order, and remove items from/in this list.
After the user is done editing the list he submits the form.

I want to empty out the table before inserting the new data.

so i call `$this->db->empty_table("myTable");`

After that i insert the new data like this:

```
$this->db->insert_batch("jcarousel",$insert);
```

The problem is: somehow the empty_table() is called after the insert query, because my table always is empty. To be clear: My insert query is working fine when i comment out `//$this->db->empty_table("myTable");`

i have tried a couple of things, so my code i a bit messed up. Right now it looks like this:

```
public function change_carousel_order($value='')
{
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    $empty = $this->empty_table();
    //$empty = TRUE;
    $form = $this->input->post();
    //print_r($form['order']);
    $insert = array();
    foreach ($form['order'] as $key => $value) {
        //echo "value: ".$value;
        $insert[$key]['product_id'] = $value;
        $insert[$key]['posistion'] = $key;

    }
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    if($empty==TRUE)
    {
        echo "jaaa";
        echo $this->insert_change_carausel_order($insert);
    }
    else{
        echo "neee!";
    }
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    //redirect("welcome/jcarousel");
}
public function empty_table($value='')
{
    return $this->db->empty_table("jcarousel");
}
public function insert_change_carausel_order($insert=array())
{
    return $this->db->insert_batch("jcarousel",$insert);
}
```

Anyone who see what i am doing wrong?
Why is'nt codeigniter inserting any data after empty_table() is called? 
Any help would be great full appreciated.

$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
tells us that there are 2 queries;
the delete query runs indeed AFTER the insert query

```
0.0003       DELETE FROM `jcarousel` 
0.0002       INSERT INTO `jcarousel` (`posistion`, `product_id`) VALUES (0,'755'), (1,'835'), (2,'838')
```

and another result same setup:

```
0.0006       DELETE FROM `jcarousel` 
0.0002       INSERT INTO `jcarousel` (`posistion`, `product_id`) VALUES (0,'755'), (1,'835'), (2,'838')
```

Comment: what you get if `var_dump($empty)` ?

Comment: var_dump($empty) returns: bool(true)

Comment: what is you get `echo $this->db->last_query();` after `$this->insert_change_carausel_order($insert);`

Comment: INSERT INTO `jcarousel` (`posistion`, `product_id`) VALUES (0,'755'), (1,'835'), (2,'838')

Comment: when and how you are calling `change_carousel_order` function. can you paste that code as well

Comment: it is a form submit. so nothing special there, the POST data is this:
 POST DATA  
$_POST['submit']   Verzenden
$_POST['order']   
Array
(
    [0] => 755
    [1] => 835
    [2] => 838
)

Comment: problem is that the Delete query gets executed AFTER the insert query

Comment: But your `enable_profiler` shows `delete` runs before `insert` and your pasted code is perfect

Comment: you are right. but still i think the delete query runs AFTER my insert query.

Comment: maybe i got it: is it because the delete function takes longer to execute than the insert query... so the delete query is called first but because of the execution time is longer, the query gets executed AFTER the insert query?

Comment: I am sure this is not the problem

Comment: OMG!!! looks like the problem is within chrome ... let me dubble check this

Comment: what the heck. it IS Chrome who is causing troubles! :$ sorry my bad not checking other browsers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was chrome's firebug plugin. this causes the page to be loaded twice, there for the second time it loads it lost all its post data.

Hope i can help someone with this (beter late then never) awnser

Answer (score 0):

I think you have spelling mistake issue.

As you stated

```
ID (int), position(int), products_id(int)
```

But in array you used as below

```
//wrong
$insert[$key]['product_id'] = $value;

//correct
$insert[$key]['products_id'] = $value;

//wrong
$insert[$key]['posistion'] = $key;

//correct
$insert[$key]['position'] = $key;
```

Comment: true i have spelling mistake, but i made the spelling mistake everywhere (except for the question). plus my insert query works fine when i command out the "$this->empty_table();" part

Comment: no,  sorry, that was not the problem i am facing check my edited Question